# Timezone database with Lat/Lng coordinates

Tags: geolocation, timezone, latitude-longitude

I'm looking for a list of timezones with polygon lat/lng information. I want to build a tool that I can punch in a lat/lng and spit out a timezone. Basically the same thing that Geonames and EarthTools does except that I don't want to have to make a web service call or depend on a third-party service with request limits.

Any suggestions on where I can find this data?

Comment: Don't forget that time zone rules change routinely during the year; different countries change their rules quite often. The current version of the [Olson](ftp://elsie.nci.nih.gov/pub/) database is 2011g. Amongst other changes this year, Russia is dropping the use of separate time zones in summer and winter; I think they're staying on 'summer' time all the time.  Even zone boundaries change; see [Samoa](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-13330592). I don't think the Olson DB includes the polygonal shapes for time zones. There are sites mentioned in the mailing list that do.

Comment: Jonathan you are confusing time zones with time offsets. Europe/Rome is always the time zone of Rome. The time offset of Rome changes twice a year (GMT+1 in winter, GMT+2 in summer). The way this offset changes is called the time zone rule.

Comment: @Micah, did you find a source?

Answer (score 1):

Look this website.

http://www.geonames.org/

Have daily updates

Comment: A pointer to a specific file to download or documentation page would have helped. If I find anything I'll post an answer.

Comment: Here is the link to their webservice: http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#timezone